# Mechanical work with curve integral (quarter circle)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, work

[image]

In this problem I want to approve the total mechanical work when an object is dragged from point A along a quarter circle with constant force $\vec{F}$ always pointing to point P. This means the direction of the force is varying although its magnitude stays the same.

In the textbook where I got the problem from it is solved using some tricks: First of the work integral is defined via:

$$W = \int F \mathrm{ds} = \int F\,\cos\theta \mathrm{ds}$$

since only the $x$-component of the force is pointing in direction of the path. Secondly the differential is rewritten using simple geometry: $\mathrm{ds} = -r \,\mathrm{d (2\,\theta)}$ thus the integral can be easily calculated:

$$ W = \int_{\pi/4}^{0} -2\,r\,F\,\cos\theta \mathrm{d\theta} = 2 \,r\,F\,\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

---

I just wonder how this is possible using the standard curve integral, no tricks:

$W = \int F\,\mathrm{ds} = \int F(\gamma(t))\,\gamma'(t)\mathrm{d t}$. The parametrisation of the curve is a well known: $\gamma(t) = r\,\left(\begin{array}{c} \cos(t) \\ \sin(t)\end{array}\right)\quad t\in[0,\pi/4]$. I only have trouble determining the force field $\vec{F}$.

My initial guess was:

$$\vec{F} = F\,\left(\begin{array}{c}\cos(2\,x_1) \\ \sin(2\,x_2)\end{array}\right)$$

But it doesn't seem to lead to the same work: $$\displaystyle W \neq  \int_{\pi/4}^{0}F\,\left(\begin{array}{c}\cos(2\,r\,\cos(t)) \\ \sin(2\,r\,\sin(t))\end{array}\right)\,r\,\left(\begin{array}{c} -\sin(t) \\ \cos(t)\end{array}\right)\,\mathrm{dt}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution:

Let the center of the circle lie on the coordinate (x,y) = (0,r). The choose the parametrisation of the curve
$\gamma(\theta) =r \begin{pmatrix} 1-\cos(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) \end{pmatrix} $

Now your $\vec{F}$ is proportional to the connecting vector between $\gamma$ and the point $(r,r)$. Therefore
$$ \vec{F} \propto r \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} - \gamma = r \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta) \\ 1- \sin(\theta) \end{pmatrix} $$
Using the correct magnitude of $\vec{F}$:
$$ \vec{F} = \frac{F}{\sqrt{2(1-\sin(\theta))}} \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta) \\ 1- \sin(\theta) \end{pmatrix}  $$

Now you can explicitly calculate your work
$$ W = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \vec{F} \cdot \dot{\gamma}d\theta = \frac{Fr}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{1-\sin(\theta)}}  d\theta = \sqrt{2}Fr $$